# NullPointerException in onProgressUpdate()

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, android-progressbar

Edit: I put this `pB = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);` in the onPreExecute(). It works, everything works. But is this a good solution? I know that in my main thread the progress bar was !null. But before this findViewById, my asynctask just couldn't find the progress bar I wanted, even though I thought I was passing it in .execute().

This is my first experience with asynctask. I have a progress bar that I want to count up, but I keep getting a NullPointerException.

The log read "Progress Update: 1" but then the VM shuts down. So I know an integer is getting passed, but I can't figure out why it can't find the progress bar(pB). I've tried to setProgress(0) in the main thread, in the onPreExecute(), but the machine hated it.

It runs the rest of the for loop in doInBackground(), and logs the "Percent Progress: " and "Sleeping " but won't log any more "Progress Update: ".

The NullPointerException is at line 31, which is pB.setProgress(progress[0]);

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...progress){
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Progress Update: "+progress[0].toString());

    super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
    if(progress[0]!=null){
    pB.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer...numSeconds){
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "doInBackground: "+numSeconds[0]);

    try {
        int totalSecs = numSeconds[0].intValue();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Total SECS: "+totalSecs);

        for(int i = 1; i <= totalSecs; i++){
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Sleeping "+i);
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            float percentage = ((float)i/(float)totalSecs)*100;
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Percentage Progress: "+ percentage);

            Float progress = Float.valueOf(percentage);
            publishProgress(new Float(progress).intValue());
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Post Execute "+ result);

    super.onPostExecute(result);

    pB.setProgress(0);
}
```

Here's some from my main thread:

To initialize the progress bar:
        timer = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        timer.setProgress(0);

To execute the asynctask:

```
OnClickListener startBubbles = new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        new ProgBar(timer).execute(100);
        setAll();
    }       
};
```

The constructor:

```
public ProgBar(ProgressBar pB){
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Constructor");

}
```

Comment: wild guess.  pB is null!

Comment: I think you might be on to something. But how do I get it to not be null? Do I have to findViewById again in my asyncTask? It should get passed from the main thread, right?

Comment: @user3067903 check if you have initialized `pB` any where. "It should get passed from the main thread, right?" Do you pass it to asynctask or is you asynctask an inner class of activity class?

Comment: findViewById can return null.

Comment: help me to understand. your asynctask is ProgBar and you pass to the constructor the progressbar object timer. Do you assign it to pB? pB = timer?

Comment: Correct: my asynctask is ProgBar and I'm trying to pass it the progress bar timer. I'll post my constructor.

Comment: do you have it in the layout you pass as argument to setContentView?

Comment: I have the progress bar and I'm sure it's the right R.id I'm initializing. (If you read my comment about it not initializing, I found that mistake).

Answer (score 0):

Null Pointer Exception occurs when you are accessing value , which is not yet been initaialized.

So for ex. char a[10];

System.out.println(a[3]);

So there must be variable within your code which you are accessing without initialising it. I thing numSecond but I am not sure.

Sorry thats all I know